# Pass the model of a view to controller's action through the MVC binding

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a file upload controller working as a backend to an EditorTemplate that holds a Kendo Core MVC Upload control.

The plan is to make this EditorControl work standalone, but I do have to pass a record Id (a Guid) to it to maintain reference.

**Controller:**

```csharp
public class UploadController : BaseControllerWithAuth<UploadController>
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment;

    public UploadController(IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccess, IUserService userService) : base(httpContextAccess, userService) => hostEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;

    public async Task<ActionResult> ChunkSave([Bind(Prefix = "IdCode.letterFiles")] IEnumerable<IFormFile>? letterFiles, string? metaData, Guid? idCode)
    {
        try
        {
            if (metaData == null)
                return await Save(letterFiles);

            var chunkData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ChunkMetaDataModel>(metaData)!;

            if (letterFiles != null)
            {
                foreach (var file in letterFiles) AppendToFile(Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, Constants.FileUploadPath, chunkData!.FileName), file, idCode?.ToString());
            }

            var fileBlob = new FileResultModel
            {
                uploaded = chunkData!.TotalChunks - 1 <= chunkData.ChunkIndex,
                fileUid  = chunkData.UploadUid
            };

            return Json(fileBlob);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex, $"{nameof(UploadController)} => {nameof(ChunkSave)}: Error: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Remove(string[]? fileNames)
    {
        try
        {
            if (fileNames == null) return Content("");

            foreach (var fullName in fileNames)
            {
                var fileName     = Path.GetFileName(fullName);
                var physicalPath = Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, Constants.FileUploadPath, fileName);

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(physicalPath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(physicalPath);
                }
            }

            return Content("");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex, $"{nameof(UploadController)} => {nameof(Remove)}: Error: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void AppendToFile(string fullPath, IFormFile content, string? idCode)
    {
        try
        {
            var basePath = Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, Constants.FileUploadPath);

            if (!Directory.Exists(basePath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath);

            var letterPath = Path.Combine(basePath, idCode!);

            if (!Directory.Exists(letterPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(letterPath);

            using var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            content.CopyTo(stream);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex, $"{nameof(UploadController)} => {nameof(AppendToFile)}: Error: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex, $"{nameof(UploadController)} => {nameof(AppendToFile)}: Error: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Save([Bind(Prefix = "IdCode.letterFiles")] IEnumerable<IFormFile>? letterFiles)
    {
        try
        {
            if (letterFiles == null) return Content("");

            foreach (var file in letterFiles)
            {
                var fileContent = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);

                var fileName     = Path.GetFileName(fileContent.FileName!.Trim('"'));
                var physicalPath = Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, Constants.FileUploadPath, fileName);

                await using var fileStream = new FileStream(physicalPath, FileMode.Create);
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }

            return Content("");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex, $"{nameof(UploadController)} => {nameof(Save)}: Error: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }

}
```

**EditorTemplate:**

```html
@model Guid?

@{
    string[] extensions = { ".jpg", ".png", ".pdf", ".ppt", ".pptx", ".doc", ".docx", ".xls", ".xlsx" };
}

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m)

<kendo-upload name="letterFiles" multiple="true">
    <async save-url="@Url.Action("ChunkSave","Upload")"
           remove-url="@Url.Action("Remove","Upload")"
           auto-upload="true"
           chunk-size="11000" />
    <validation allowed-extensions="@extensions" max-file-size="36700160" />
</kendo-upload>
```

Note the `[Bind(Prefix = "IdCode.letterFiles")]` in the Controller's Actions. I had to figure that out because of the Upload control being in an EditorTemplate. Also, on the parent View, this is how the EditorTemplate is placed:

```html
    @using (Html.BeginForm("", "Letter", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IdCode)

        <div class="panel mt-20px" data-sortable-id="ui-widget-16">
            <div class="panel-heading bg-da-blue text-white">
                <h4 class="panel-title">RL Info</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m, "Letter")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel mt-20px" data-sortable-id="ui-widget-16">
            <div class="panel-heading bg-da-blue text-white">
                <h4 class="panel-title">Attachments</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.IdCode, "LetterAttachmentsManage")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100 me-5px" formaction="CreateSave" title="@(Model.IsUpdateCase ? "Update letter" : "Save letter")">@(Model.IsUpdateCase ? "Update" : "Save")</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default w-100" formaction="CreateSubmit" title="@(Model.IsUpdateCase ? "Update letter & submit" : "Save letter & submit")">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

I am in a situation where I trigger the View passing the Guid. Once the view is rendered as partial, I can upload a file(s) through the Kendo control, and it posts to the ChunkSave `method` on the controller. I need to pass the value of the View's model too.

I thought that by simple adding a same-name and type parameter: `Guid? idCode` to the `ChunkSave` action on the controller would be enough but apparently not though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my Upload controls as:

```xml
<kendo-upload name="letterFiles" multiple="true"
              on-upload="letterFilesOnUpload" on-remove="letterFilesOnRemove" on-complete="letterFilesOnComplete"
              on-success="letterFilesOnSuccess" on-error="letterFilesOnError" on-cancel="letterFilesOnCancel">
    <async save-url="@Url.Action(nameof(UploadController.ChunkSave), ControllerExtensions.Nameof<UploadController>())"
           remove-url="@Url.Action(nameof(UploadController.Remove), ControllerExtensions.Nameof<UploadController>())"
           auto-upload="true" chunk-size="2097152" concurrent="true" />
    <validation allowed-extensions="@extensions" max-file-size="36700160"/>
</kendo-upload>
```

And here is how handled the events while passing the custom data, where needed:

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function letterFilesOnUpload(e) {
        $('#IsBusy').val('True');
        e.data = {
            letterGuid: $('#LetterGuid').val()
        };
    }

    function letterFilesOnRemove(e) {
        $('#IsBusy').val('True');
        e.data = {
            letterGuid: $('#LetterGuid').val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

And on the controller side, I slightly modified the signature of the methods by adding the `Guid? letterGuid`:

```sc
public class UploadController : BaseControllerWithAuth<UploadController>
{
    ...

    public async Task<ActionResult> ChunkSave(IEnumerable<IFormFile>? letterFiles, string? metaData, Guid? letterGuid)
    {
        ...
    }

    public ActionResult Remove(string[]? fileNames, Guid? letterGuid)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```